# so i want to be able to add the answer of the calculations to my history text box, how can i do it?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import math
expression=""

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('calculator')
    root.geometry("400x550")
    root.config(bg='#404040')
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    
    
    
    
    def press_button(num):
        global expression
        expression = expression +str(num)
        input_text.set(expression)
        
    def clear_button():
        global expression
        expression= ""
        input_text.set("")
        
    def equal_button():
        global expression
        result =str(eval(expression))
        input_text.set(result)
        expression=""
        
        
    expression=""
    input_text=StringVar()
    
    frame =tk.Frame(root,width=400,height=300)
    frame.configure(borderwidth=5,relief='ridge')
    frame.place(x=1,y=1,width=400,height=550)
    frame.config(bg='#586F7C')
    
    number_entery = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=input_text)
    number_entery.place(x=10.5,y=100,width=370,height=70)
    number_entery.config(bg='#499F68',font='Arial 20 bold')
    number_entery.configure(borderwidth=3,relief='sunken')
    
    button_number_0 =tk.Button(frame,text='0',command=lambda:press_button(0))
    button_number_0.place(x=60,y=400)
    button_number_0.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_0.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_dot=tk.Button(frame,text='.',command=lambda:press_button('.'))
    button_number_dot.place(x=100,y=400)
    button_number_dot.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_dot.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_ngpo=tk.Button(frame,text='+/-',command=lambda: press_button('-'))
    button_number_ngpo.place(x=135,y=400)
    button_number_ngpo.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_ngpo.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_eq=tk.Button(frame,text='=',command=lambda: equal_button())
    button_number_eq.place(x=188,y=400)
    button_number_eq.config(bg='#499F68',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_eq.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_1=tk.Button(frame,text='1',command=lambda: press_button(1))
    button_number_1.place(x=60,y=350)
    button_number_1.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_1.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_2=tk.Button(frame,text='2',command=lambda: press_button(2))
    button_number_2.place(x=100,y=350)
    button_number_2.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_2.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_3=tk.Button(frame,text='3',command=lambda:press_button(3))
    button_number_3.place(x=140,y=350)
    button_number_3.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_3.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_4=tk.Button(frame,text='4',command=lambda: press_button(4))
    button_number_4.place(x=60,y=300)
    button_number_4.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_4.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_5=tk.Button(frame,text='5',command=lambda: press_button(5))
    button_number_5.place(x=100,y=300)
    button_number_5.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_5.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_6=tk.Button(frame,text='6',command=lambda:press_button(6))
    button_number_6.place(x=140,y=300)
    button_number_6.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_6.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_7=tk.Button(frame,text='7',command=lambda: press_button(7))
    button_number_7.place(x=60,y=250)
    button_number_7.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_7.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_8=tk.Button(frame,text='8',command=lambda: press_button(8))
    button_number_8.place(x=100,y=250)
    button_number_8.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_8.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_9=tk.Button(frame,text='9',command=lambda: press_button(9))
    button_number_9.place(x=140,y=250)
    button_number_9.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_9.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_number_delete=tk.Button(frame,text='C',command=lambda: clear_button())
    button_number_delete.place(x=180,y=350)
    button_number_delete.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_number_delete.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_function_add = tk.Button(frame,text='+',command=lambda: press_button('+'))
    button_function_add.place(x=180,y=250)
    button_function_add.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_function_add.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_function_subtract = tk.Button(frame,text='-',command=lambda: press_button('-'))
    button_function_subtract.place(x=222,y=250)
    button_function_subtract.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_function_subtract.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_function_division = tk.Button(frame,text='÷',command=lambda: press_button('/'))
    button_function_division.place(x=180,y=300)
    button_function_division.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_function_division.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_function_multiply = tk.Button(frame,text='x',command=lambda: press_button('*'))
    button_function_multiply.place(x=220,y=300)
    button_function_multiply.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_function_multiply.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    button_function_columen = tk.Button(frame,text='()',command=lambda: press_button(')'))
    button_function_columen.place(x=220,y=350)
    button_function_columen.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
    button_function_columen.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
    def calculate_cosine(angle):
        clear_button()
        number_entery.insert('end',math.cos(angle))

    def calculate_sin(angle):
        clear_button()
        number_entery.insert('end',math.sin(angle))
        
    def calculate_tan(angle):
        clear_button()
        number_entery.insert('end',math.tan(angle))
        
    def calculate_sqrt(num):
        clear_button()
        number_entery.insert('end',math.sqrt(num))
        
    def factorial(num):
        clear_button()
        number_entery.insert('end',math.factorial(num))
        
    def log(num):
        clear_button()
        number_entery.insert('end',math.log(num))
    def display_complex_function():
        button_function_cos = tk.Button(frame,text='cos',command=lambda:calculate_cosine(int(number_entery.get())))
        button_function_cos.place(x=270,y=250)
        button_function_cos.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
        button_function_cos.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
        
        button_function_sin = tk.Button(frame,text='sin',command=lambda: calculate_sin(int(number_entery.get())))
        button_function_sin.place(x=330,y=250)
        button_function_sin.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
        button_function_sin.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
        
        button_function_tan = tk.Button(frame,text='tan',command=lambda:calculate_tan(int(number_entery.get())))
        button_function_tan.place(x=270,y=300)
        button_function_tan.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
        button_function_tan.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
        
        button_function_sqrt = tk.Button(frame,text='sqrt',command=lambda:calculate_sqrt(int(number_entery.get())))
        button_function_sqrt.place(x=325,y=300)
        button_function_sqrt.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
        button_function_sqrt.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
        
        button_function_fact = tk.Button(frame,text='n!',command=lambda: factorial(int(number_entery.get())))
        button_function_fact.place(x=280,y=350)
        button_function_fact.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
        button_function_fact.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
        
        button_function_log = tk.Button(frame,text='log',command=lambda: log(int(number_entery.get())))
        button_function_log.place(x=320,y=350)
        button_function_log.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
        button_function_log.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
        
    def display_history():
        
        root.geometry('800x550')
        
        frame_2 =tk.Frame(root)
        frame_2.configure(borderwidth=5,relief='solid')
        frame_2.place(x=400,y=1,width=400,height=550)
        frame_2.config(bg='#586F7C')
        
        
        label = tk.Label(frame_2,text='history')
        label.pack()
        label.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
        label.configure(borderwidth=1,relief='groove')
        
        text_box=tk.Text(frame_2,width=400,height=100)
        text_box.insert('1.0',input_text.get())
        text_box.pack()
        text_box.config(bg='#C5C6D0',font='Arial 15 bold')
        
        def remove_cal():
            frame_2.destroy()
            root.geometry("400x550")
        
        button_remove_history = tk.Button(frame_2,text='Close',command=remove_cal)
        button_remove_history.place(x=149,y=490)
        button_remove_history.config(bg='#4682B4',font='Arial 15 bold')
        button_remove_history.configure(borderwidth=2,relief='raised')
    
        
   
    menu = tk.Menu(root)
    menu2 = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
    menu2.add_command(label='history',command=display_history)
    menu2.add_command(label='complex functions',command=display_complex_function)
    menu2.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.destroy)
    menu.add_cascade(label='Options', menu=menu2)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    
    root.mainloop()
    
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

This is my code. I used `tkinter` for the calculator, I made it so that the main root will extend and the history will appear so I know its local and I cant access it but is there another way for me to insert that data to the history box?

Comment: Please check your formatting

Comment: Do u want something like this 7+9=16 in history?

Comment: Another calculator where every single button is manually coded... I have 3 words for you "use a loop". You could turn that ?50? lines into like 5. A little bit of clever divmod usage and it can all be laid out in a perfect grid using the same calculation repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

> so i want to be able to add the answer of the calculations to my
> history text box, how can i do it?

Snippet:

```
def equal_button():
    global expression
    result = expression + '=' + str(eval(expression)) #<== Add this
    input_text.set(result)
    expression=""
```

Screenshot:

[image]